# What would be the consequence of higher oxygen level in water

Tags: biology, sea

Related to this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/43920/how-could-water-breathing-animals-have-a-warm-blooded-level-of-metabolism/43924) on the topic of [merfolk](/questions/tagged/merfolk). What would be the consequence of higher oxygen level in water?

As far as I know it is at 14 to 15 mL per liter with a water temperature at 0°C. (Higher temperatures, less oxygen)

Would we just get bigger fish?

---

**Edit:**

For clarification, by higher oxygen level, I actually mean an higher possible maximum oxygen saturation. Instead of the 14 mL per liter water, 140 mL per liter water at zero degree. So we get closer to the amount of oxygen in the air.

Comment: Less efficient fish perhaps but there are some pretty big fish out there

Comment: Generally, changing something arbitrary about physics breaks everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just add more in analogy with the way air has a percentage of oxygen. It holds as much as it does due to the laws of physics, and the air above will supply as much as the water can take up.

You would have to change the properties of water and/or oxygen so it desolves more. Or lower the temperature.

[image: oxygen vs temp]

This graph is found [here](http://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/parameters/water-quality/dissolved-oxygen/#6) which also covers *What Affects Oxygen Solubility?* generally. This is a great article to go through.

That's how you can observe the answer: look at the sealife in arctic vs warm water. The abundance of life in colder water is due to increased oxygen levels there.

Another idea is to increase the oxygen at depths where it is currently *not* saturated. This entails more mixing. This normally happens with wave action over reefs, currents that sink oxygen-rich surface water, and storms.

Comment: Yeah, the thought was to higher the possible saturation of water (changing the physical rules of the world). Maybe I should stated this in the question. Sorry for the inaccuracy.

Comment: Wait, can't you fit more oxygen into the water when you _raise_ the temperature? After all, that makes the water molecules more spread apart with more room for oxygen.

Comment: Nope. Heat of solution can be considered a reaction product on one side of the equilibrium relation. And spacing of water molecules doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: http://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/parameters/water-quality/dissolved-oxygen/   *First, the solubility of oxygen decreases as temperature increases ¹. *